Tensorflow Lite .tflite model - improve latency of Google Cloud bucket retrieval object for Inference
I'm following the Image Classification code at MediaPipe. My model runs successfully, it is smaller than EfficientNet. However the latency of inference I get is 5 seconds.
MediaPipe .tflite object, at:
https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-models/image_classifier/efficientnet_lite0/float32/1/efficientnet_lite0.tflite
... loads instantly, with an inference time of milliseconds.
I tried with a regional bucket and fine-grained permissions but it didn't solve the problem. I am also using the https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxxx/model.tflite Public URL but it didn't solve the problem. CORS file of the bucket is configured as the following:
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://your-example-website.appspot.com"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]

Do you have any ideas how to improve object retrieval latency ?

Have you considered to make the inference locally? There are flutter packages that can handle tflite models on-device.

Same problem locally....
